# How to search in MongoDB an element depending on the previous one?

Tags: mongodb

I'm having to deal with a query that is kind of strange. I'm creating an app for boat tracking: I have a collections of documents with the timestamp and the Port ID where it was the board at that moment.

After sorting all the documents of this collection by the timestamp descending, I need to grab the elements that have the same Port ID in that range of time.

For example:

```
timestamp                | port_id
2021-11-10T23:00:00.000Z | 1
2021-11-10T22:00:00.000Z | 1
2021-11-10T21:00:00.000Z | 1
2021-11-10T20:00:00.000Z | 2
2021-11-10T19:00:00.000Z | 2
2021-11-10T18:00:00.000Z | 2
2021-11-10T17:00:00.000Z | 1
2021-11-10T16:00:00.000Z | 1
2021-11-10T15:00:00.000Z | 1
```

Having this data (sorted by timestamp), I would have to grab the first 3 documents. The way I'm doing this now, is grabbing 2000 documents and implementing a filter function in the application level.

Another approch would be grabbing the first element, and then filtering by that port id, but that returns me 6 elements, not the first 3.

Do you know any way to perform a query like this in Mongo? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `$setWindowFields()` would be an option. Can you provide sample input data and result

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$setWindowFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "",
      sortBy: { timestamp: -1 },
      output: {
        c: {
          $shift: {
            output: "$port_id",
            by: -1,
            default: "Not available"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      c: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $eq: [ "$port_id", "$c" ] },
          then: 0,
          else: 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "",
      sortBy: { timestamp: -1 },
      output: {
        c: {
          $sum: "$c",
          window: { documents: [ "unbounded", "current" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: { c: 1 }
  },
  {
    $unset: "c"
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nBDmeDxLPjc)